# NodeJS Zappa using @response, @request in called functions

Tags: node.js, function, scope, zappa

I can do this:

```
require('zappajs') ->
    @get '/':-> console.log(@response)
```

but when I try this

```
require('zappajs') ->
    @get '/': -> foo()

    foo = ->
      console.log(@response)
```

@response is undefined. So obviously 'this' is now out of scope. I tried using the `=>` function definition instead of `->` which is meant to pass 'this' through ... but it makes no difference. 
I can achieve the desired result using a @helper

```
require('zappajs') ->
    @get '/':-> @foo()

    @helper foo: ->
        console.log(@response)
```

Is that the only way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You're losing scope when you're calling your function like that `foo()`, to keep the scope, you have to call `foo` like that:

`foo.apply(this)` or `foo.call(this)`